# Suggested Server Specs

Tags: hosting

I am going to host 5 magento websites which include about 1000 products max each, about 25k visits per month each(max). I don't want to buy a server and waste its resources, either struggle so looking for suggestion on whats the best number of cores/RAM for a package like this?

Comment: what size your database ? you will have to calculate from that

Comment: You need much more than 2gb, I would suggest a minimum of 32gb

Answer (score 2):

For software specs you can check http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

For the database please find a hosting provider that supports Percona MySQL

For hardware with a setup like this I'd say 2GB RAM and 2CPU should be enough but it depends a lot on how well the shop was built and the type of caching you are using.

Some tips on server configuration can also be found here: https://www.mgt-commerce.com/blog/magento-on-steroids-best-practice-for-highest-performance/

Comment: i would not be so sure about 2GB RAM, this advice is like a shot in the dark. calculation is coming from database size. and whether Percona or mysql version 5.6 would be good. that page at mgt-commerce is not correct and weird copy-paste.

Comment: @MagenX this is not a shot in the dark. This is from having set up dozens of shop. As I said, it depends on a lot more than the information given in the question but it has some foundation. But if you know it so much better feel free to add your own answer

Comment: i can not answer until we know the database size, unfortunately it can be 1Gb or even 10Gb, if he follow your advise, eventually he will tear the hair on the ass...

Comment: @MagenX first of all thank you both for your replies. To give you a bit more information, my largest store database is around 599.28 MB. Few more information is that my site which is currently on VPS, its homepage size is 2.27MB with about 74 HTTP requests.